# How to filter full file name or full folder name only from input path using batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

**I am running the following command,**

```
set /p "filepath=Drag and drop your file >" 
cls 
for %%a in ("%filepath%") do echo %%~nxa
pause >nul
```

It works good when the file name is single word. But, it doesn't works when the file name or folder name is multiple words containing space in between.

**Example & Output am getting running above code is,**

**(1)** if input path is `D:\folder\folder\file.txt` then, the output is,

```
file.txt
```

**(2)** if input path is `D:\folder\folder name\file name.txt` then, the output is,

```
folder
file
name.txt""
```

**But, Expected Output for (2) is,**

```
file name.txt
```

Kindly help me to fix my code.

Comment: use `for /f "delims=\"`

Comment: but, the input folder name and location may different every time. Also the file name may differs and its length change.depends on user providing file path and name..

Comment: @Akina kindly help :(

Comment: When you're ready for **PowerShell**, it's a one-liner: `(Read-Host 'Drag and drop (or type) file here:').Split('\')[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
set /p "filepath=Drag and drop your file >" 
set filepath=%filepath:"=%
:repeat
for /f "delims=\ tokens=1*" %%x in ("%filepath%") do (
    set filename=%%x
    set filepath=%%y
)
if "%filepath%"=="" (
    echo %filename%
) else (
    goto :repeat
)
endlocal
```

Comment:  Huge Thanks. It works. U saved my time. Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 1):

A short option keeps only the last string based on delimiter `\` in `set !var:\=!`

```all-bat
set "_var_file=c:\this\folder\and\this\subfolder\of\this\file name and extension.log"
```

- Source/Credits: **[Split string into substrings based on delimiter by Sponge Belly / DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)**

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p "filepath=Drag and drop your file >" && set "filepath=!filepath:"=!"
set "_name=%filepath:\=" & set "filepath=%" & cls & call echo/!filepath! 
"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t -1 & endlocal
```